# Can I apply jQuery on manually created document model?

Tags: javascript, jquery, web-scraping, fetch

I am trying to scrape some webpage, doing some searching I get to know about fetch API.

I have fetched a webpage using fetch() API from an URL , then I parsed the page into a DOM object, Now I have whole webpage in a DOM object. Can I apply jQuery functions on that?

my code

```
async function getProductData(url)
{
  try {
    const resp = await fetch(url);
    var respText = await resp.text();
    var parser = new DOMParser();
    var doc = parser.parseFromString(respText, 'text/html')

    // I am trying to do something like that. is it possible to do so ?
    $(doc).ready( function(){
      console.log( $( this) .find( $("#productTitle") ).text() );
    });

   }
  catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}
```

.ready is not mandatory for me. I just need to extract some data from doc object. if there is any better way to fetch data from webpage please let me know, it would be very helpful for me.
Thank you so much.

Comment: Why would you use jQuery in new code to begin with? :/

Comment: I am developing a chrome extension, for that I need to extract data from different pages.is there any better way to extract data from url without not visiting the webpage?

Comment: `doc.querySelector('#productTitle').innerText`

Comment: Yeah, there's pretty much no need for jQuery anymore nowadays!

Comment: `$(doc).ready..` is invalid and will never run

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need and jQuery here:

```js
const resp = await fetch(url);
const respText = await resp.text();
const parser = new DOMParser();
const doc = parser.parseFromString(respText, 'text/html');
console.log(doc.querySelector('#productTitle').innerText);
```